# How can I convert cathodic energy efficiency to overall energy efficiency?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry, energy, electrolysis, reduction-potential

Im working on calculation which involve the energy efficiency of producing formate by CO2 electroreduction.

I wonder how to convert the reported cathodic energy efficiency (71%) of papers e.g (1) [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/smtd.201900846) or (2) [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jz1012627) into an overall energy efficiency.

I want to assume that water is oxidized at an anode. If needed we can plug in an assumed efficiency for the anode reaction.

I am relatively new to electrochemistry, and trying to learn so forgive me if this is trivial, but I can barely find the term "cathodic energy efficiency" online for me to learn this.

[image: Paper 1]

[image: Paper 2]

Comment: If the efficiency is not $100$%, it means that the rest of the electric energy is lost in heat by the Joule effect.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to estimate what is the loss of energy on the anode side for these kind of papers?

Comment: @Maurice I think the <100% cathode energy efficiency they report of producing the desired product (formate)  is also result of the competing HER reaction, and not just heat.

Comment: You may be right, after all. Why not ?